# formal argument "data" matched by multiple actual arguments in R

Tags: r

When I run the following codes in R,

```
library(mclust)
data(iris)
mc <- Mclust(iris[,1:4], 3)
plot(mc, data=iris[,1:4], what="classification",dimens=c(3,4))
table(iris$Species, mc$classification)
```

I got an error meesage for the `plot`:

```
Error in coordProj(data = data, what = "classification", parameters = object$parameters,  : 
  formal argument "data" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

I am not sure what went wrong with the data subset `data=iris[,1:4]`. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: plot.Mclust lacks a 'data' parameter (but it is used by sub-functions).  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: Thanks for the hint! It works after deleting the data= argument. The result is a plot showing classification.

Comment: The problem was, that the `data` argument in your `plot` command is passed through to `plot.Mclust`, which passes through to smaller functions - along with another argument called `data`.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: thanks again for the explanation :) Yes, the generic plot function calls plot.Mclust() as mc is of class Mclust, so I guess there must be something wrong with the overlap of the data= argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about deleting the data= and leaving

```
plot(mc, what="classification",dimens=c(3,4))
```

Answer (score 3):

That might be old, but hope it would help somebody else.

1. The first argument of the function `plos(..)` represents the data.
2. The argument `data=...` in the function `plos(...)` reprersents the data

As a result, `r` recognizes multiple datasets since you are suggesting more than one data