# predictions from Mclust model object error: 'formal argument "data" matched by multiple actual arguments'

Tags: r

I'm trying to load a saved Mclust model object to predict new data but receive the following error:

```
> pred = predict(uclust,nudata)
Error in cdens(data = c(0.00184267068950098, -0.00190583873737998, 0.00151479724106021,  : 
formal argument "data" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

where the model object is loaded from a saved .rda as below:

```
library('mclust')
...
udata = structure(c(0.0019187831006595, -0.000201933721230549, 0.00647683016806048,     0.00570825969274979, 0.00448955455678227, 0.00203021228043293, 0.0013439660297503, 0.0061740641668618, 0.00168185804869739, 0.00122819057525598, -0.00185588921560545,  5.57491063920656e-06, -0.000605253452992944, 0.00163308609318636, -0.00208562661302523,  -0.00180485182447247, -0.000950634510672036, -0.000709762485647883, -0.00183425286477769, -0.000277804799146203), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("v9", "v4")))
uclust = Mclust(udata)
#save model object
save(uclust,file='clusterobject.rda')
...
rm(uclust)
load('clusterobject.rda')
pred = predict(uclust,udata)
```

I've read from another SO question ( [formal argument "data" matched by multiple actual arguments in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547302/formal-argument-data-matched-by-multiple-actual-arguments-in-r) ) that this is due to subfunctions requiring a "data" parameter.  How do I pass this required "data" parameter in to the subfunctions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved with the install update of Mclust package version 4.3 as the original problem was occurring in version 4.2.